# load json into excel using office js web addin

Tags: excel, office-js

if I have json string which looks like this: [{"id":1,"name":"manish"},{"id":1,"name":"John"}]
can I just office js to simply load it in table. I saw this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-tables#import-json-data-into-a-table
but then when I add more columns in my json I will have to do code changes and code is not generic enough. I could live with it but was wondering if there is a better way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.keys(obj).length` to count the number of properties in one of your JSON objects. Something like `myObjects[0].keys(obj).length`.

Then get a `Range` object for the cell that will be the upper-left cell of the table; for example, `getRange("A1")`.

Then use that `Range` object's `getResizedRange` method and pass 1 as the first parameter (rows) and pass the number of properties in your JSON object as the second parameter (columns).

Use the `Range` object that is returned by `getResizedRange` as the first parameter to the `sheet.tables.add` method.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on [@RickKirkham answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50416307/5079799) and the link in the OP from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-tables#import-json-data-into-a-table I build a "more generic" approach. My issue was that I have no control over the JSON response, I don't know how many rows, columns etc. I first tried to just use `A1` and expected it to expand as needed, but that didn't work.

I did finally get it to work as I wanted below:

```
var transactions = [
    {
        "DATE": "2017",
        "MERCHANT": "The Phone Company",
        "CATEGORY": "Communications",
        "AMOUNT": "120"
    },
    {
        "DATE": "2017",
        "MERCHANT": "Southridge Video",
        "CATEGORY": "Entertainment",
        "AMOUNT": "40"
    }
];

var sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getItem("Sheet1");
var rng = sheet.getRangeByIndexes(0, 0, 1, Object.keys(transactions[0]).length)
var expensesTable = sheet.tables.add(rng, true);
expensesTable.name = "ExpensesTable";
expensesTable.getHeaderRowRange().values = [Object.keys(transactions[0])];

for (let i = 0; i < transactions.length; i++) {
    expensesTable.rows.add(null, [Object.values(transactions[i])]);
}

if (Office.context.requirements.isSetSupported("ExcelApi", "1.2")) {
    sheet.getUsedRange().format.autofitColumns();
    sheet.getUsedRange().format.autofitRows();
}

sheet.activate();
```

PS: Very  new to JS/Office JS atm.